# I'm using multibib to have references at the end of each chapter but the numbering is wrong

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, multibib

I am using `multibib` to have references at the end of each chapter but when I have the same reference in multiple chapters, the numbering in the text corresponds to the last chapter that the reference appears in.

The numbering in the reference sections are all fine and `hyperref` works correctly.

As an example, currently I get something like this:

> Chapter 1
>
> I cite ann [4], bob [2] and cat [3].
>
> References for Chapter 1
>
> 1 ann 2 bob 3 cat
>
> Chapter 2
>
> I cite dug [4], ed [5] and ann [6].
>
> References for Chapter 2
>
> 4 dug 5 ed 6 ann

So I should get ann turning up as ref 1 in chapter ref 3 in chapter 2.

Comment: Hi and welocme. Without any code it will be very difficult or nearly impossible to help you. You should create a minimal working example that illustrates your problem. This should contain only commands and definitions relevant to this problem and an excerpt from your bib-file as well

Comment: OK it looks like a limitation of multibib. [Thorsten Hansen](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/multibib.pdf) has this to say: "When numerical reference schemes are used and references to the same item
appear in diﬀerent bibliographies, the labels cannot be resolved properly.
Rather, the replacement text (i.e, the number) is used which is deﬁned in
the auxiliary ﬁle read last."

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of `multibib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibib) lists the following limitation:

> When numerical reference schemes are used and references to the same
>   item appear in diﬀerent bibliographies, the labels cannot be resolved
>   properly. Rather, the replacement text (i.e, the number) is used which
>   is deﬁned in the auxiliary ﬁle read last.